# Sauce url is undefined, for multiremote scenario

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io, saucelabs

I have a test case, which requires interaction between multiple instances of the browser.
to create multiple instances, i am using the approach suggested in the following webdriver io api link - 
*http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/multiremote.html*

```
export.config = {
// ...
capabilities: {
myChromeBrowser: {
desiredCapabilities: {
browserName: 'chrome'
}
},
myFirefoxBrowser: {
desiredCapabilities: {
browserName: 'firefox'
}
} 
}
// ...
};
```

At the end of the execution of test case, sauce url is getting printed like as below -

```
06:43:16 [undefined #0-0] 22 passing (8m, 5s)
06:43:16 [undefined #0-0] 63 pending
06:43:16 [undefined #0-0]
06:43:16 [undefined #0-0] Check out job at https://saucelabs.com/tests/undefined
06:43:16 [undefined #0-0]
```

Expectation:
I need some valid url, which should redirect me to the correct sauce lab record.